# check if any cells in a range are blank

Tags: excel

Ive got a range of cells C1:R10 each with a dropdown with 5 selections including 1 blank value.

I want to add another column in S that will check cells C:R on each row, to see if any cells are blank.

Ive tried using an `ISBLANK` but this dosnt seem to work, what else could be used here ?

Comment: `countblank` perhaps?

Comment: @Jeeped that worked, thanks !

Comment: If there is a Leading Apostrophe in cell (this defines text format) then `ISBLANK` function returns false but  `COUNTBLANK` adds 1. You can delete cell too. Leading apostrophe is added automatically when simple pasting as text from cells that their formula results in empty text (for example `=""`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using countblank. Note that it will consider cells that appear blank but are not (such as ones that contain only spaces) as not blank.

=countblank(C1:R10)

Comment: Nice, so basically: =IF(COUNTBLANK(C1:R1)>0;FALSE;TRUE)

Comment: A good rule with Boolean functions is that if you are putting true and false it, you're doing it wrong. Try =NOT(COUNTBLANK(C1:R1)>0) for the same result as what you wrote.